# AUTHENTICATION error while running Azure emulator (how to fix this please)

Tags: c#, azure

I am having some ugly problems with the Azure Emulator, well the main thing is that it keeps trying to connect to my local address and it does not find a proxy for it and the emulator fails to initialize my web role(obviously)

Error :

```
WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED
```

I know there are questions like this, but everyone replies "it should not be connecting to your local address, change it"...I know that, now, could anyone tell me how do I change it?